# How to Use the Returned Value (a list) from one function in a new function to print the list as a csv at the user's desired file path

Tags: python, function, csv

```
 def find_qualifying_loans(bank_data, credit_score, debt, income, loan, home_value):
      monthly_debt_ratio = calculate_monthly_debt_ratio(debt, income)
      print(f"The monthly debt to income ratio is {monthly_debt_ratio:.02f}")

      # Calculate loan to value ratio
      loan_to_value_ratio = calculate_loan_to_value_ratio(loan, home_value)
      print(f"The loan to value ratio is {loan_to_value_ratio:.02f}.")

      # Run qualification filters
      bank_data_filtered = filter_max_loan_size(loan, bank_data)
      bank_data_filtered = filter_credit_score(credit_score, bank_data_filtered)
      bank_data_filtered = filter_debt_to_income(monthly_debt_ratio, bank_data_filtered)
      bank_data_filtered = filter_loan_to_value(loan_to_value_ratio, bank_data_filtered)

      print(f"Found {len(bank_data_filtered)} qualifying loans")

      return bank_data_filtered

def save_qualifying_loans(qualifying_loans)
```

This new function is supposed to first verify if the amount of qualifying loans is 'None', in which the program can terminate after a goodbye message. Next, if there are qualifying loans, I need to save the qualifying loans from above found in the return value 'bank_data_filtered' as a csv file. The program user is supposed to select the desired output path on their computer. How do I even begin writing this new function? Thank you.

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})


def saveCsv(df,filepath, filename):
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(filepath,filename))

saveCsv(df,filepath='/home/ashleyubuntu/Documents',filename='df.csv')
```